# Importing dictionary values into an OptionMenu in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm stuck right now and could really use some help, i've exhausted every resource google could find for me and I still can't figure out how to do what I am attempting. (If its even possible)

In my python program I am using Tkinter in Python 3.5.1 to make a little calculator applet. For the calculator in question I created a CSV file and imported it using csv.DictReader.

```
import csv
exptable = csv.DictReader(open('C:/Users/SampleInfo.csv'))

result = {}
for column in exptable:
    key = column.pop('Current Level')
    if key in result:
        pass
    result[key] = column
```

Now the part that I simply can't figure out is how to use the information contained WITHIN this imported dictionary. Here is what I am trying so far...

```
DropDownLevelVar = StringVar()
DropDownLevel = ttk.OptionMenu(root, {column})
DropDownLevel.grid(column=3, row=1)
```

This is leaving me with...

```
Error on line 49, in module DropDownLevel = ttk.OptionMenu(root, {column})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The CSV Dictionary I am trying to use contains 2 columns of data, "Current Level and Total EXP" See [This for what the Data looks like.](http://irowiki.org/classic/Base_EXP_Chart)

What I would like is for the OptionMenu Dropdown list to be populated with the values listed under Current Level within the dictionary.

My goal is to create a super simple calculator that calculates how many of a certain monster I would need to kill to reach my desired level. (If Current level = 55, then 100 Kills at 500xp ea until 56.) I imported the dictionary so that I could reference the values over and over if I needed to.

I'm REALLY new to programming so i'm sorry if I look like a complete idiot!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [this method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to populate your dict?

Anyway, to correctly populate the `result` dict:

```
import csv
exptable = csv.DictReader(open('C:/Users/SampleInfo.csv'))

result = {}
for column in exptable:  # should actually be called `row`
    key = column['Current Level']
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = column['Total EXP']
```

The `for` and `if` block can be better written as:

```
for column in exptable:  # should actually be called `row`
    if column['Current Level'] not in result:
        result[column['Current Level']] = column['Total EXP']
```

If `ttk.OptionMenu` wants a dict, then the line `DropDownLevel = ttk.OptionMenu(root, {column})` should probably be:

```
DropDownLevel = ttk.OptionMenu(root, result)
```

Edit: And the pythonic way to do this, as per the method linked above:

```
import csv

result = {}
with open('C:/Users/SampleInfo.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Current Level'] not in result:  # is this check necessary?
            result[row['Current Level']] = row['Total EXP']
```

Comment: Dang perfect! Thank you so much for the help!! I did my import this way just because I am new, your method seems much more clean!